# Converting pointer-to-pointer to 2D array

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function that looks like this

`float Determinant(unsigned int n, float a[][n])`

and I want to pass a double pointer

`float **a`

is there a way to cast `float **a` to `float a[][n]`?

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to do that. The array `a`, when declared as a function parameter, decays into a pointer to the first element, an array pointer of `float (*)[n]`. Neither this array pointer type nor the array `float a[][n]` have anything to do with the type `float**`.

The need to pass a `float**` to this function probably originates from flawed program design. Perhaps you are mistaking dynamically allocated, pointer-based look-up tables for 2D arrays? If so, see [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: Thank you so much!